# How to debug "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo"?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to call a new Activity("OtherActivity") when I click on the action item in the action bar... but it gives me java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo.

I have specified the both the MainActivity and OtherActivity in the manifest.xml file.

```
package com.example.notice;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.action_settings);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new               Intent(MainActivity.this,OtherActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

And this is my LogCat

```
12-08 01:51:38.118: E/AndroidRuntime(2823): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-08 01:51:38.118: E/AndroidRuntime(2823): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.notice/com.example.notice.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-08 01:51:38.118: E/AndroidRuntime(2823):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
12-08 01:51:38.118: E/AndroidRuntime(2823):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
12-08 01:51:38.118: E/AndroidRuntime(2823):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-08 01:51:38.118: E/AndroidRuntime(2823):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
12-08 01:51:38.118: E/AndroidRuntime(2823):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-08 01:51:38.118: E/AndroidRuntime(2823):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-08 01:51:38.118: E/AndroidRuntime(2823):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-08 01:51:38.118: E/AndroidRuntime(2823):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-08 01:51:38.118: E/AndroidRuntime(2823):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-08 01:51:38.118: E/AndroidRuntime(2823):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-08 01:51:38.118: E/AndroidRuntime(2823):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-08 01:51:38.118: E/AndroidRuntime(2823):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-08 01:51:38.118: E/AndroidRuntime(2823): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-08 01:51:38.118: E/AndroidRuntime(2823):     at com.example.notice.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
12-08 01:51:38.118: E/AndroidRuntime(2823):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
12-08 01:51:38.118: E/AndroidRuntime(2823):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-08 01:51:38.118: E/AndroidRuntime(2823):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
12-08 01:51:38.118: E/AndroidRuntime(2823):     ... 11 more
```

OtherActivity

```
package com.example.notice;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class OtherActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_other);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.other, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: If you need an answer ASAP then you should probably post the complete logcat, ASAP, so that we can see the error

Comment: you better post your logcat message !

Comment: Did I do something stupid???
M new to android...

Comment: The Views should be constructed completely before using them

Comment: The problem is in the `MainActivity` not `OtherActivity`. See my answer for an explanation.

Comment: @new_jerry FYI: unfortunately you can only accept one answer by clicking the check mark. I see it going through all of them ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there is no `Button` in `activity_main.xml` with the `id` of `action_settings`. So you get a `NPE` when you try to set the `OnClickListener` on it. If that is from a `menu` then you need to use the `onOptionsItemSelected()`.

We know this because looking at these two lines here

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-08 01:51:38.118: E/AndroidRuntime(2823):     at     
com.example.notice.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
```

it says that something is `null` at line 17 of `MainActivity` which is where you set your `listener`, meaning that it wasn't intitalized properly.

[OnOptionsItemSelected Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#RespondingOptionsMenu)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this line

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.action_settings);
```

is a trouble maker: make sure you init your btn properly - looks like it's null

Comment: yea...i thought that menu buttons could also be handled like any ordinary button...thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 0):

the action_setting is a menu item not a Button inside the activity layout so you should use the button name (inside the activity layout 'R.layout.activity_main') . not the menu item